# How to persist redux slice of the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

The state is set, but I'm not entirely sure why my extraReducers state is not persisting to storage on page refresh. I tested a state setter for just `reducers` and it persisted perfectly fine on page refresh.

Store.ts

```
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'

import { createWhitelistFilter } from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { blockchainSlice } from 'slices'

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
  whitelist: ['blockchain']
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, combineReducers({
  blockchain: blockchainSlice.reducer
}))

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    },
  }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store)

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

blockchainSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { Contract } from "web3-eth-contract";
import Web3 from "web3";

import { RootState } from 'root';

declare let window: any;

export interface BlockchainState {
  contract: Contract | null,
  ethWeb3: {
    connected: boolean,
    instance: Web3 | null,
    walletAddress: string | null
  }
}

const initialState: BlockchainState = {
  contract: null,
  ethWeb3: {
    connected: false,
    instance: null,
    walletAddress: null
  }
}

export const initWeb3Instance = createAsyncThunk(
  'blockchain/initWeb3', async (thunkApi) => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts')

      let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
  
      let address = await web3.eth.getAccounts().then(addr => addr[0].toLowerCase())

      return { instance: web3, walletAddress: address }
    } else {
      alert('Please install Metamask!')
    }
  }
)

export const blockchainSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'blockchain',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(initWeb3Instance.fulfilled, (state, { payload }: any) => {
      state.ethWeb3.connected = true
      state.ethWeb3.instance = payload.instance
      state.ethWeb3.walletAddress = payload.walletAddress
    })
  },
})

export default blockchainSlice
```

I use `useAppSelector` to confirm that state gets set, but looking at local storage, nothing changes, and on page refresh it doesn't persist. Highly confused and would like for another eye on what might be the problem here. Thank you!

`const { connected, instance, walletAddress } = useAppSelector((state) => state.blockchain.ethWeb3)`

Answer (score 0):

## What happen when we refresh a page inside a redux app ?

When you refresh a page you are re-creating a store with the initial state, so if you want to keep some slice information when you refresh you need to store them

## Which storage should I use to persist a slice ?

Based on your platform and the privacy of the information, you can use different solutions. For basic information like wallet address on your app you can use the local storage. You can only put serialisable object. Seems your **instance is a class instance** so you **cannot serialise** it

## How to persist redux state in local storage ?

You can use redux persist to persist slice inside the localstorage and having them when you reload the page https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

## Only put serialisable object in the state

if `ethWeb3.instance` is a class instance and not a serializable object this is a wrong pattern. State should be serializable so you cannot set a class. This is why you cannot persit it

## Where to put class instance with redux ?

I think your instance can live inside a middleware for example.